# Understanding pricing breakup for Google Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Below table explains the cost breakup for one month - actual numbers from my account.
I am interested in knowing about two components below - what do they mean/Why are they changed and how to eliminate/minimize those costs.

1. Idle Min-Instance Memory Allocation Time (tier 2)
2. Idle Min-Instance CPU Allocation Time (tier 2)

GCP documentation has good explanation about other price components - Invocations, CPU Time, Network Egress &  Memory Time but not the above two. In my case, those two components are the most costly once.

[image]

Comment: That is actually explained in the pricing docs you mention https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#idle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [cloud functions pricing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) page it's pretty clear

[image]

You have a pricing per tiers (depending of [your region](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations#tier_2_pricing)). The min instance idle is the price that  you pay when you set a min-instance > 0, and therefore you have to pay full price of the memory and 10% of the CPU price. See the price in parenthesis.

The idle time means that your instances are kept warm but without any processing on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps. So looks like, even if I don't use the function, it is still going to get changed :)